# Before/After spec not working as expected

Tags: cypress

In my Cypress configuration I have a before and after spec:

```js
on('before:spec', () => {
    console.log('before spec');
});
on('after:spec', () => {
    console.log('after spec');
});
```

When I do `cypress:run` I see the before and after logged with each spec. But when I run `cypress:open` I see a the `before spec` when I open the Cypress client, not when I open the spec. The `after spec` is also not logged when the test is finished, but rather when the Cypress client is closed.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-spec-api):

> The after:spec event fires after a spec file is run. When running
> cypress via cypress open, the event will fire when the browser closes.

and

> When running via cypress open, the after:spec event only fires if the experimentalInteractiveRunEvents flag is enabled.